# How to open two instance of chrome driver concurrently without get any error?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I open a first instance of chrome driver and works fine until I try to open second instance (with other profile). Once I try to open second instances this is happens

1. the Second instance open the browser but stop in the line web=uc.Chrome....
2. First instance continue running until finish.
3. The second instance wait a time and rise thes error below.
4. If first instance close and the code try to open another instance, I got same error.

I have this code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
opt = uc.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", f"localhost:{port}")
opt.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opt.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
opt.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
opt.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
opt.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
profile_dir = 'C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data'
profile_chrome = 'Profile 2'
opt.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_dir}")
opt.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile_chrome}")
web = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=opt)
```

The variable port is an integer number selected from a list where every profile has a port number from 10000 to 10010

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\begin.py", line 520, in <module>
    __toolbox()

  File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\begin.py", line 46, in __toolbox
    run_option(opt)

  File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\begin.py", line 366, in run_option
    run_pending_actions()
  
File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\run_pending_actions.py", line 36, in run
    open_browsers_one_by_one()
  
File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\run_pending_actions.py", line 87, in open_browsers_one_by_one
    just_social_life(brw, sel_id)
  
File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\run_pending_actions.py", line 130, in just_social_life
    web = load_profile(profile, browser=brw, update_prof=False)
  
File "C:\Users\myuser\_Python1\__facebook_no_async\login.py", line 196, in load_profile
    web = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=opt)
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 443, in __init__
    super(Chrome, self).__init__(
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 674, in start_session
    super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:11254

from chrome not reachable

Stacktrace:

Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0053A813+48355]

        (No symbol) [0x004CC4B1]

        (No symbol) [0x003D5220]

        (No symbol) [0x003CB355]

        (No symbol) [0x003F5C68]

        (No symbol) [0x003F06B4]

        (No symbol) [0x003F0491]

        (No symbol) [0x00420C55]

        (No symbol) [0x0042093C]

        (No symbol) [0x0041A536]

        (No symbol) [0x003F82DC]

        (No symbol) [0x003F93DD]

        GetHandleVerifier [0x0079AABD+2539405]

        GetHandleVerifier [0x007DA78F+2800735]

        GetHandleVerifier [0x007D456C+2775612]

        GetHandleVerifier [0x005C51E0+616112]

        (No symbol) [0x004D5F8C]

        (No symbol) [0x004D2328]

        (No symbol) [0x004D240B]

        (No symbol) [0x004C4FF7]

        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76AF7D59+25]

        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77D7B79B+107]

        RtlClearBits [0x77D7B71F+191]
```

Comment: don't set debuggerAddress... let driver choose port... also make sure you are not using the same user-data-dir for 2 sessions.